# android Mp4Parser merge issue

Tags: android, mp4parser

I need to merge audio(in aac format) and video (mp4 format). I use mp4parser library for this.

```
public static boolean mergeMP4withAAC(String videoFilePath, String audioFilePath, String outFilePath) {
    try {
        /* Load a MP4 file as movie */
        Movie movieVideo = MovieCreator.build(videoFilePath);

        /* Fetch needed audio track and video track from MP4 file */
        Track audioTrack = new AACTrackImpl(new FileDataSourceImpl(audioFilePath));
        Track videoTrack = movieVideo.getTracks().get(0);

        double t1 = 1.0 * videoTrack.getDuration() / videoTrack.getTrackMetaData().getTimescale();
        double t2 = 1.0 * audioTrack.getDuration() / audioTrack.getTrackMetaData().getTimescale();
        Log.d(TAG, t1 + " " + t2);

        double factor = (t1 * audioTrack.getTrackMetaData().getTimescale()) / audioTrack.getDuration();
        Log.d(TAG, "factor = " + factor);

        /* Construct a movie */
        Movie movie = new Movie();
        if (factor < 1.0) {
            long trackSize = audioTrack.getSamples().size();
            long sampleNeeded = (long) (trackSize * factor);

            Log.d(TAG, (trackSize - sampleNeeded - 1) + " " + trackSize);

            movie.addTrack(videoTrack);
            movie.addTrack(new CroppedTrack(audioTrack, trackSize - sampleNeeded - 1, trackSize));
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "mergeMP4withAAC 1");
            long trackSize = videoTrack.getSamples().size();
            long sampleNeeded = (long) (trackSize / factor);
            movie.addTrack(new CroppedTrack(videoTrack, trackSize - sampleNeeded - 1, trackSize));
            Log.d(TAG, "mergeMP4withAAC 2");
            movie.addTrack(audioTrack);
            Log.d(TAG, "mergeMP4withAAC 3");
        }

        /* Build it */
        Container mp4file = new DefaultMp4Builder().build(movie);
        Log.d(TAG, "mergeMP4withAAC 4");
        /* Write resulted MP4 to file */
        FileChannel fc = new FileOutputStream(new File(outFilePath)).getChannel();
        Log.d(TAG, "mergeMP4withAAC 5 " + mp4file.getBoxes().size());
        mp4file.writeContainer(fc); // the problem I guess may be here
        Log.d(TAG, "mergeMP4withAAC 6");
        fc.close();
        Log.d(TAG, "mergeMP4withAAC 7");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

But when I have resulted video file longer then 5-6 mins, some devices stops working (it means UI is frozen, user can't do nothing, but Android doesn't show any messages, the only one way to resume app is to restart device).

I have logged every row as you can see in code snippet, and I got that problem is in a row where I write resulted file to the disk.

Also I have tested it on the different devices. Moto G (1gen), Moto G(2gen) (Android 5.0.2) and Nexus 5 (Android 5.1.1) can't merge file longer then 5-6 mins, but Nexus 7 (Android 5.1.1) can merge files longer then 10 mins.

So can somebody explain me something about this or give some advices or examples. Thanks a lot.

Comment: this usually happens when there is a memory leak, or you are doing too much work on the main thread

Comment: no, I call this method from asynctask, and it can't be memory leak because the max memory usage is near 50 Mb, CPU level is less then 20%, but GPU is overload. the device is dead after merging, we even can't stop it or do something else

Comment: the video conversion is usually taken care of by the GPU, if GPU is getting overloaded then you have to spend time on thinking of a way to give it lesser load